# How can I change a CPLEX parameter in my Julia code?

Tags: julia, cplex

I'm using the CPLEX solver to run my ILP model.The ILP model is implemented with Julia/MultiJuMP.

I would like to limit the time of optimization of the problem.  If I were working with OPL, I would just have to add `Cplex.tilimt=100`

In Julia, I put the following code :

```
mmodel = MultiModel(solver = CplexSolver("CPLEX.tilim"=100), linear = true)
```

It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the last section in https://github.com/JuliaOpt/CPLEX.jl/blob/master/README.md, it appears that Julia uses the legacy parameter names as they appear in the C API of CPLEX. For example, `CplexSolver(CPX_PARAM_EPINT=1e-8)`.

Here's the link to the the CPLEX documentation for that parameter: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/EpInt.html. As you can see, the name appears as the first row in the 'Name prior to V12.6.0' column.

For the time limit, you should thus use `CPX_PARAM_TILIM`, as this is the name in https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/TiLim.html.